# Loki freezes every few hours since monday 6/3

Tags: release-loki, graphic-drivers, crash

I think that since I've installed an update on March 6, i started to experience freezes in the system 
Every few hours everything suddenly freezes and leaves no option but to restart the laptop. There's no slowness prior to the freeze.
Any suggestions on debugging of this?
Thank you!

Machine: Intel® Core™ i7-4810MQ CPU @ 2.80GHz × 8
15.3 GiB
Intel Corporation 4th Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
NVIDIA Corporation GK106GLM [Quadro K2100M] (rev a1)
39.5 GB

Prior to freeze found these lines in the system logs:

```
nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 0a [CTXSW_TIMEOUT]
```

Comment: Investigating this further: This is not related to multiple displays (freezes with one display same as with multiple). Not related to Corsair mouse driver.

Comment: Prior to freeze found these lines in the system logs  nouveau 0000:01:00.0: fifo: SCHED_ERROR 0a [CTXSW_TIMEOUT]. Installed Original NVidia driver

Comment: Related: [Ubuntu 18.04 desktop hangs](https://askubuntu.com/q/1036581/78223) & [Ubuntu 16.04 desktop hangs occasionally during regular use](https://askubuntu.com/q/874307/78223)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution: change the driver to original Nvidia driver instead of Nouveau driver. Issue was resolved.[How To Switch to NVidia driver](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/Nvidia)

Answer (score 0):

This is the bug of Nouveau video driver (kernel extension). For details, check the bugs at [bugs.freedesktop.org](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/buglist.cgi?bug_status=__open__&content=SCHED_ERROR&list_id=663471&no_redirect=1&order=Importance&query_format=specific) or at [GitLab](https://gitlab.freedesktop.org/), especially: [#93629](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=93629), [#99900](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=99900) and [#100567](https://bugs.freedesktop.org/show_bug.cgi?id=100567) (which are related to `SCHED_ERROR`/`CTXSW_TIMEOUT`).

For more details, check: [Ubuntu desktop hangs occasionally during regular use](https://askubuntu.com/q/874307/78223).